# Multiple classpaths when running Ant taskdef?

Tags: java, jar, ant, classpath

I have an ANT script that calls a Java 11 class using a custom classpath

```
<path id="ant.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/ant">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="myTaskDef" classname="A.SomeClass" classpathref="ant.classpath" />
```

The ${basedir}/lib/ant directory contains several jars

- A.jar - My library
- B.jar - Third-party library
- C.jar - Third-party library, different company than B.Jar

These jars all load into the classpath ${ant.classpath} just fine.

The workflow is like this: 
A.jar calls B.jar, and B.jar calls C.jar.

So, A.jar calls classes in B.jar no problem. It uses the import statement in JAVA to call the classes:

```
import B.SomeClass;
```

This works perfectly.

However, B.jar calls C.jar and it fails.

I was able to inspect the source code code for both third-party libraries and have learned that B.jar calls classes from C.jar using Java's Classloader class. It doesn't use the import statement.

Below is code from a class inside B.jar

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
....
classLoader.loadClass("C.SomeClass");
```

The exception that I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C.SomeClass
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at B.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
```

I was able to verify that C.SomeClass does exist in C.jar.

I suspect that it's loading a different classpath than the one provided by the ant taskdef. When I try to load the C.jar class from within my library (A.jar) using the ClassLoader, I get the same exception. But import works just fine.

I'm sort of at a loss at what to do because I can't get B.jar to properly load C.jar through Ant.

EDIT:

In case it's useful, I'm using Java 11, and B.jar is really jaxb-api-2.4.0.jar (javax.xml.bind) and C.jar is jaxb-runtime-2.4.0.jar (com.sun.xml.bind) plus its dependencies (jaxb-core, stax-ex, txw2, etc). I get the ClassNotFoundException, when I call:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Feature.class);
```

And it can't find the class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory, which I've confirmed does indeed exist.

Comment: Have you run ant in verbose mode? It should show you what all .jars are loaded into classpaths. Though this is not a solution, this will provide you insight if all required jars are loaded in classpath. Also if any unwanted jars are part of classpath that might be creating problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I messed around in A.jar and learned that getClass().getClassLoader() and Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() return different things. The getClass().getClassLoader() contains the ANT classpath that I set in the ANT script, the the Thread classloader does not.

I can't change the code in B.jar since it's a 3rd-party library, however, I was able to set the Thread's classloader in my code using the following:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
```

I put this in the code right before my code calls B.jar, and subsequently C.jar. It worked perfectly!